# Drawing a Ferrers diagram

Tags: graphs, grids

Probably as easy question, I know. But how do I draw something like this:

[image]

I know how to draw a 5x5 grid, but I'm not sure how to remove squares from it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This can be done with a tabular or TiKz

Answer (score 8):

Since there are already so many answers, one more does not hurt. It's based on the youngtab package.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{youngtab}
    \usepackage{amsmath}  

    \begin{document}
    \[\young(~~~~~,~~c~,~~~,~~~,~)\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A version with `tabular` and one with `TikZ`, of course the output with `TikZ` is much better than this very simple `tabular` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{C{0.2cm}|}}
\hline
& & & &  \tabularnewline
\hline
& & C & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{1-4}
& & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{1-3}
& & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{1-3}
&  \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}

\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, line width=1pt]
  \draw (0,0) grid (5,1);
  \draw (0,0) grid (4,-1);
  \draw (0,-1) grid (3,-2);
  \draw (0,-2) grid (3,-3);
  \draw (0,-3) grid (1,-4);
  \node[left] (A) at (3,-0.5) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A very short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pstricks, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(5.5,5.5)
\psclip{\pspolygon(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(3,1)(3,3)(4,3)(4,4)(5,4)(5,5)(0,5)}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0](0,0)(5,5)
\endpsclip
\rput(2.4,3.4){C}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A grid has the disadvantage that the horizontal and vertical lines are drawn independently. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[x=1em, y=1em]
  \draw[ultra thick]
    (0, 0) grid[step=1em] (1, 1)
    (2, 0) -- (3, 0) -- (3, 1) -- (2, 1) -- cycle
  ;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The missing squares in the grid of the question increase the number of such corners. There are now seven instead of four corners. Therefore, the example draws the outer lines first as closed polygon to get the correct line joins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[x=1em, y=-1em]
  \draw
    % Border as closed polygon for better corners.
    (0, 0) -- ++(0, 5) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(0, -1) -- ++(2, 0)
    -- ++(0, -2) -- ++(1, 0) -- ++(0, -1) -- ++(1, 0)
    -- ++(0, -1) -- cycle
    % Horizontal lines
    (0, 1) -- ++(4, 0)
    (0, 2) -- ++(3, 0)
    (0, 3) -- ++(3, 0)
    (0, 4) -- ++(1, 0)
    % Vertical lines
    (1, 0) -- ++(0, 4)
    (2, 0) -- ++(0, 4)
    (3, 0) -- ++(0, 2)
    (4, 0) -- ++(0, 1)
    % Cells
    (2.5, 1.5) node {c}
  ;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]